# How to set a Predefined Field Value lookup field by ID?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lookup, action

I created an Opportunity Action, using the `OpportunityLineItem` as the Target Object. I want to set a Predefined Field Value for the field `PricebookEntryID`. When I add a new predefined value, select the lookup field (Price Book Entry) and set the formula to `'[some-pbe-id]'`, I end up with this error (which makes sense):

> Error: Formula result is data type (Text), incompatible with expected data type (Lookup(Price Book Entry)).

How can we set an ID using the formula editor?  I read that it is now possible in Winter14.

Source: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/he-il/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_chatter_new_mdp_predefined_field_types.htm

> You can now predefine values for lookup and master-detail fields.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While lookup and master-detail fields are supported, this is only in terms of being able to reference a value from another field.  So I have a scenario where an account can only have opportunities with a specific pricebook, so I have populated a lookup to the pricebook on the account object.  I can then predefine the pricebook on a "new opportunity" publisher action with the following formula:

```
Account.Price_Book__c
```

Unfortunately you can't pass in the id of a specific record as a literal.

Comment: What about the `Price Book Entry` field? It sounds impossible to use, considering we can't build custom lookups to the PricebookEntry object.

Comment: You are correct - it doesn't seem very useful.  I expect this feature has been enabled for all lookup/master-detail fields regardless of whether its actually possible to use it.